# order of calling synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading

i believe, this is a simple question, but still, i don't get it on my own. Say, i have following code.

```
Runnable objectRunnable = new Runnable() {
    void run() {
          synchronized(object) {
              for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                  System.out.println("it's runnable");
                  Thread.sleep(100); 
              }
          }
    }
};

void doSomething() {
    synchronized(object) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("it's doSomething");
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}

synchronized (object) {
    new Thread(objectRunnable).start();
}
object.doSomething();
```

So, the output is like

```
it's doSomething
it's doSomething
it's doSomething
it's doSomething
it's doSomething
it's runnable
it's runnable
it's runnable
it's runnable
it's runnable
```

Question is why `doSomething()` goes before thread? Moreover, if i put multiple calls of object methods after synchro block, they all be called subsequently, and only then program returns to the content of thread. If i replace that thread calling line in synchro block with, say, calling some analog object method, than everything is ok, and goes in specified order.

Do methods of synchronized object itself have some kind of priority in execution before any threads, synchronized on this object?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a race condition: your runnable gets blocked waiting on a monitor upon starting up due to `synchronized (object)` around its creation. Once the thread creating runnable releases the monitor, the newly created thread with runnable does not get a chance to grab it, because the same thread re-enters it again in the `doSomething()` method.

If you add a call to `Thread.sleep(100);` before calling `object.doSomething()`

```
synchronized (object) {
    new Thread(objectRunnable).start();
}
Thread.sleep(100); // <<== Add this line
object.doSomething();
```

the order of printouts will reverse ([demo](http://ideone.com/5FrPq6)).

```
it's runnable
it's runnable
it's runnable
it's runnable
it's runnable
it's doSomething
it's doSomething
it's doSomething
it's doSomething
it's doSomething
```

Comment: it clears things a bit, but still, why then after sychronized creation of runnables, threads are not called next? it looks logical to me, that since we call `start()` on this threads in a code and it goes before `doSomething()`, they should be put like on the top of stack of called methods, and not let current thread grab monitor before them

Comment: @idementia Thread is started next, but it gets blocked right away, because the parent thread is still holding the lock. Once the parent thread releases the lock, it's up for grabs, but the same thread is, in a way closer to grabbing it, because it's already running, while the other thread is blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Because the main thread is the first one to obtain the lock. It could have been the spawned thread, you just can't be sure, although that's much less likely, because it takes some time after calling start() for the thread to actually start running.

Regarding the rest of your question, it's much too vague to be answered.